# Microsoft Graph API Query Users with a filter on proxyAddresses

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to build an app that uses the Microsoft Graph API to lookup other users by email address. Unfortunately I also need to lookup by alternative/proxy email addresses and I am struggling to find the scope required for the API call.

Using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I can successfully submit the query `/beta/users?$filter=proxyAddresses/any(x:x eq 'smtp:user.name@example.com')` but when running in the app I get an insufficient permissions error.

```
{
  "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
  "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
}
```

The app is written using node and the `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client` NPM package and following the [tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/node-tutorial).

The query looks like this in node:

```
let result = await client
    .api('/users')
    .version("beta")
    .filter('proxyAddresses/any(x:x eq \'smtp:' + email + '\')')
    .get();
```

It works when I use a simpler query, for example:

```
let result = await client
    .api('/users')
    .version("beta")
    .filter('mail eq \'' + email + '\'')
    .get();
```

And it doesn't matter what version I use either, I get the same results. So I was thinking it has something to do with the `proxyAddresses` property but I don't know why it would work in the explorer and not here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Required scope will be User.Read.All

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like you need to update your scope list to include a missing scope. I don't know what the scope is that you need, but what I would do is in Graph Explorer, after you are logged in, I'd open the console and run tokenPlease() to get your access token. Compare the scopes in the access token returned by Graph Explorer to the scopes that you request in your app to help you determine which scope you still need to request.

Comment: Thanks for the tokenPlease() suggestion, that helped a lot! Using this token in my app and the permission problems went away, so it is a scope problem.

What would be nice is if Graph Explorer could tell you what scopes were checked/used/required in the request?

Comment: @ORogers, thank you for the feedback. That would be a **very** useful feature.